# How to close ios app in Delphi-XE5 Firemonkey application?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I do not manage to find how to end an application iOS in Delphi XE5 Firemonkey.

Application.terminate does not work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

In iOS it is not allowed to close an App. You can only force a crash. Apple will not allow Apps with this behavior in their AppStore. 
An alternative an be to set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to Yes (in the info.plist file).
=> When the user presses the home button your application will be ended.